# How to run Laravel 5.3 on server without Vhosts

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5.3, vhosts

I have a Laravel 5.3 website, but now that I want to put it online on my server, I realize that I can't change the vhosts to make it work properly.

How can I make my website work, without vhost? I now that Zend Framework can run just fine using only `.htaccess` configurations. That is a way of doing it for Laravel?

The solution should allow the website to work both ways: with and without the vhosts!

Answer (score 1):

This is may help.
copy everything from myproject/public to public_html

open public_html/index.php and set:

```
require DIR.'/../myproject/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once DIR.'/../myproject/bootstrap/start.php';
```

and put this on top:

```
ini_set('eaccelerator.enable', 0);
```

Last create a .htaccess file on root directory.
Create an .htaccess file on your laravel's root directory. 
This is to access it without the "public" on the url.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I was looking for a solution that doesn't involve change the files and structure of my application... there is a way of doing it only using .htaccess or something like that? thanks!

Comment: @Bikash Paul, I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030097/how-to-add-some-textfield-in-form-register-laravel-generator-infyom